# How to invoke my function in plugin in FireBreath

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebreath

In Firebreath Plugin development , after creating plugin we have to use below code to use plugin.

```
<object type="application/x-telugu-spell-checker" id="plugin" style="width:0px;height:0px;">
        <param id="plugin1" value="alert('Plugin Loaded');"> 
</object>
```

Above code is to access our plugin , I think,
Now when I access the plugin immediately a function has to be called, how can I do that

It's like when we create an object to a class , if we have a constructor it will automatically invoked when object is created, exactly when I access the plugin by using above code I want to call a function

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want is to have a single param called `onload` that is the name of a global javascript function to be called. Also note that setting it to 0px by 0px can cause issues in some browsers; set it to 1px by 1px, you won't see it.

```
<object type="application/x-telugu-spell-checker" id="plugin" style="width:1px;height:1px;">
    <param id="onload" value="pluginLoaded"> 
</object>
```

Then in javascript anywhere:

```
window.pluginLoaded = function() {
    alert('Plugin Loaded');
};
```

Comment: I have implemented one method in javascript in the cpp file. I don't want to call my function in javascript in my webpage script, when plugin is loaded in my page that function has to be called automatically , is it possible

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please ask one question at a time on a thread, and when you get an answer mark it as correct.  The question you're asking in your comment is fundamentally a completely different question than the one asked above, and belongs on a different question.  I see that you have done that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504743/how-to-start-the-javascript-function-in-my-firebreath-plugin -- it shouldn't be here as well

Comment: I am new to this, but I am about to finish my project in two days so I want to know the solution as early as possible, so please suggest me the way to do that