# how to start the javascript function in my firebreath plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, firebreath

I have implemented a javascript function in firebreath plugin file 'MyPluginProject.cpp'

like

```
void MyPluginProjectAPI::MyJsThings()
{
    std::string argument = "my javascript functionality goes here";

    m_host->evaluateJavaScript(argument);
}
```

Now to use the MyJsThings in my webpages I have created <object> for the plugin.
Now I can call MyJsThings by calling it in my javascript code like below

```
plugin.MyJsThings()
```

This is the very basic thing.
Now I don't want to call MyJsThings method in my javascript. I am just creating object for the plugin by below code.

```
<object type="application/x-my-plugin-project" id="plugin" style="width:0px;height:0px;">
        <param id="onload" value="alert('Plugin Loaded');"> 
</object>
```

When I load my page I want my method MyJsFunction has to be called so that my js functionalities will do the remaining things.
My main aim is to call the function  MyJsFunction when the plugin is loaded, not in any where in the html script.

Comment: I'm really not understanding what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you just trying to get some C++ code to execute when the plugin is loaded and ready? If so, you want to override onPluginReady in your main plugin object...  if not, please clarify your question.

Comment: Problem solved by just calling the function in onPluginReady Class

Comment: Note that you can't put an arbitrary javascript string in onload, you need to put a function name.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want is to use the onPluginLoad method in your PluginCore-derived object.

Note that you would have found this if you'd read the getting started pages on the website and/or looked through the FBTestPlugin example -- highly recommended reading.